# Two LWE samples with the same secret

Tags: hardness-assumptions, lwe

I am considering the following problem related to Learning with Errors. Recall that the LWE assumption is that no adversary can distinguish $(A,As+e)$ from $(A,u)$ with non-negligible advantage, where $A\in\mathbb Z_q^{m\times n}$ and $u\in\mathbb Z_q^m$ are random and $e\in\mathbb Z_q^m$ is a random vector each element of which is drawn from some error distribution e.g., discrete Gaussian. The secret $s$ is a random vector sampled from $\{-1,+1\}$.

The problem is as follows: you are given either $(A_1, A_2, A_1s+e_1, A_2s+e_2)$ or $(A_1,A_2, u_1,u_2)$, where $A_1,A_2$, $u_1,u_2$, $e_1,e_2$ are sampled independently as in the decisional LWE problem. The goal is to decide which is the case. The difference from LWE is that it is promised that the two vectors in the first tuple encode the same secret.

Is it known the problem is hard? I've tried to give a reduction to LWE, but did not succeed. For example, view $A'=(A_1,A_2)$, $s'=(s^\top,s^\top)^\top$, $u'=(u_1^\top,u_2^\top)^\top$ and $e'=(e_1^\top,e_2^\top)^\top$ (concatenations of two column vectors into a column vector). The problem becomes to distinguish $(A's'+e')$ from $(A',u')$. But here $s'$ is not a uniform vector from $\{-1,+1\}^{2n}$, so it's not guaranteed to be hard.

Comment: Assume that you can distingush. Can you see how you can use this to distinguish LWE?

Comment: You should consider the problem with $A=(A_1^t,A_2^t)^t$ and the same $s$ instead. (Check the dimensions of vectors!)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The dimensions did not match in my attempt. Let $A=(A_1^\top, A_2^\top)^\top$ as Hhan suggested. Then the problem becomes to distinguish $As+e'$ from $u'$. By the LWE assumption the problem should be hard.